# How to predict healthy of leaf using image processing technique?

Tags: image-processing, classification, bayesian, prediction, matlab-cvst

Hi i want to predict health level(High,medium,low) in leaf using image processing and data mining.So far i thought using extract colors from leaf using Bayes algorithm to predict healthy of leaf. and data mining part have completed now.but i need extra features for prediction.we only used orchid leaf.So i can't use vain structure.Can anyone help me to what are the other features can be extracted from leaf for identify health level of leaf.Any idea or comments help me to improve my project. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible approaches to a problem like this. One common method is the bag-of-features model. Take a look at this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html) using the Computer Vision System Toolbox in MATLAB.